# How do I get class from NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsobject

for example, I have

```
NSString *myClass = @"RootViewController"
```

How do I get class from NSString?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
 id obj= [[NSClassFromString(@"RootViewController") alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"RootViewController");
```

> NSClassFromString
>
> Obtains a class by name.
>
> Class NSClassFromString (    NSString *aClassName );
>
> Parameters
>
> aClassName
>
> ```
> The name of a class.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The class object named by aClassName, or nil if no class by that name
>   is currently loaded. If aClassName is nil, returns nil. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

There is a lot of methods like this in foundation framework

```
NSGetSizeAndAlignment
NSClassFromString
NSStringFromClass
NSSelectorFromString
NSStringFromSelector
NSStringFromProtocol
NSProtocolFromString
```

Refer [Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"RootViewController");
```