# Objective-C class for property with name

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, how can I achieve something like this:

```
Class propertyClass = [self classForPropertyWithName:@"a_property"];
```

Comment: This is very unclear what you are after.

Comment: I don't think so. I have the name of a property of my class. I want to get the class of that property by its name.

Comment: Do you mean something like `[[self valueForKey:@"a_property"] class]` (although this would fail for primitives)?

Comment: So why not just `Class propertyClas = [[self a_property] class];` ?

Comment: Because "a_property" is a string. valueForKey: is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could break it into two steps.

1. Get a property by name (via `-valueForKey:`)
2. Get the class of the property (via `-class`)

Something like this maybe (note that this will fail for non object types):

```
Class propertyClass = [[self valueForKey:@"a_property"] class];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the object with property named "key" using this method:

```
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
```

ie:

```
object = [valueForKey:@"propertyName"];
```

Then to get the class type you simply call the class method which is available for all object types except primitives.

```
Class classType = [object class];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535860/how-do-i-get-class-from-nsstring). Code:

```
Class c = NSClassFromString(@"RootViewController");
```

Another option:

```
id object = // Fetch here;
Class c = [object class];
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(c);
```

Documentation: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString)

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I asked for. I want to get the class of a property. I don't know the class name, I just know the property name.

Comment: Then look at my edited answer now. You should write your question more concrete.